# Вывести атрибут родителя Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Где ошибся? Пытаюсь вывести атрибут родителя, но выдает undefined

```js
$("body").on("click",'.comment--item .rcomment', function() {
    let comment = $(this).parent('.comment--item').attr('data-id');
    console.log(comment);
});
```

```html
<li class="comment--item" data-id="25356">
  <div class="comment--user">
    <div class="comment--footer">
      <div class="btn--action">
        <button class="btn-link rcomment">Ответить</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Ссылка</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Пожаловаться</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Поделиться</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените parent на parents

```js
$("body").on("click",'.comment--item .rcomment', function() {
    let comment = $(this).parents('.comment--item').attr('data-id');
    console.log(comment);
});
```

```html
<li class="comment--item" data-id="25356">
  <div class="comment--user">
    <div class="comment--footer">
      <div class="btn--action">
        <button class="btn-link rcomment">Ответить</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Ссылка</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Пожаловаться</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Поделиться</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

То же самое, только на чистом `js`, просто для общего развития )

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click',
  e => {
    if (e.target.matches('.comment--item .rcomment')) {
      const dataId = e.target.closest('.comment--item').dataset.id
      console.log(dataId)
    }
  })
```

```html
<li class="comment--item" data-id="25356">
  <div class="comment--user">
    <div class="comment--footer">
      <div class="btn--action">
        <button class="btn-link rcomment">Ответить</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Ссылка</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Пожаловаться</button>
        <button class="btn-link">Поделиться</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```